# Qt cross-compile desde Windows a Linux Embedded?

Tags: qt, embebido

Por más que busque y relee la documentación y wikis de Qt no acabo de entender la manera de conseguir compilar para un target diferente al del host. Sé que se recomienda usar Linux como entorno de desarrollo pero el objetivo es que sea desde Windows.

[Aquí](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html) dicen de usar la herramienta `configure` lo que no se especifica es ¿cómo?

Partiendo de un proyecto ejemplo cualquiera, lo abro con Qt Creator, y entonces ¿qué hago? ¿Cuales son los pasos?

El host es **Windows 7** usando **Qt 5.7** (compilador MinGW 5.3). 
El target es **Debian Wheezy** (kernel 3.0.55) en una placa con chip iMX6Q.

Comment: Para Raspberry pi hay varios tutoriales. El proceso será el mismo (o parecido).

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar montajes cruzados necesitas:

- Un compilador que te permita crear ejecutables en el entorno de destino.
- Una versión de Qt compilada con dicho compilador.

Con esta base ya puedes empezar a configurar el entorno. Lo primero que tienes que hacer es dar de alta el compilador en QtCreator para que Qt sea capaz de compilar aplicaciones con el mismo. El compilador se puede dar de alta desde Tools -> Options -> Compilers.

Después hay que configurar un "kit". Los kits indican a Qt qué conjunto de librerías de Qt se ha de usar con cada compilador. Esta parte se configura desde Tools -> Options -> Kits (en versiones antiguas de Qt creo que se llamaba *Toolchains*).

Una vez has completado estos dos pasos cada vez que crees un proyecto nuevo podrás elegir compilar usando tu nueva configuración. Para proyectos ya creados tendrás que editar el proyecto para añadir los nuevos kits a las posibilidades de compilación.

Un saludo.

Comment: Oook, es decir, primero necesito descargarme el codigo fuente de Qt (qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0.zip) para que lo compile y configure para el target deseado.  A ver si lo consigo.